# Access - Sorting by MonthName and populating all dates in a given month

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

1) I am making a dynamic sized Crosstab query in Access. My columns display months which are passed in from a local table. I then use MonthName() and display each month by yyyy/mmmm. The problem is that when I use the sort Ascending option, my dates are displayed Alphabetically instead of Chronologically.

2) In a separate table I am also having trouble figuring out how to create rows for all days in a given month. I would also like it to not display duplicate dates if they are already in the query.

For example: 
If I have a table with a date column, and the entries 1/5/2013, 1/17/2013, and 5/27/2013 in that table, I would like it to display the following:

```
  DATE         
1/1/2013
1/2/2013
1/3/2013
...
...
1/30/2013
1/31/2013
5/1/2013
5/2/2013
5/3/2013
...
...
5/30/2013
5/31/2013
```

Thanks for any help you might be able to give.

Answer (score 1):

There's no issue *displaying* the month name, but your `ORDER BY` should be on the `DATE` field.

Comment: You are right in that the months display as they should. The problem is with the sorting. I am new to access and am confused on how to use the ORDER BY clause in the query. When in design view I am using Year([AssignmentDetails].[Entry Date]) & " / " & MonthName(Month([AssignmentDetails].[Entry Date])) to display the dates.

Comment: @Crash, just add the `ORDER BY [DATE]` to the end of the query.